# I hope that my colleagues will expand on this

Tags: grammar

'will' has different usages, for certainty in the future, making predictions, conditional sentences, intentions and decisions, willingness and offers, requests and invitations, promises, commands.
 I think 'will' in the sentence bellow announced 'invitation', am I right?

> I hope that my colleagues will expand on this.

I asked a question in a Forum one of the teachers answered my question and in the end of his answer, he wrote that sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much, AndyT. Should I write 'one of the teachers'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"will" in this context just means "future". Whether it's a certainty, a prediction, a conditional or an invitation depends on the rest of the sentence and also context.

Your sentence, if delivered in a flat tone, with your colleagues nowhere near, expresses a hope for the future. If delivered with a rising tone, while turning towards your colleagues who are sitting next to you, it is clearly an invitation to your colleagues to stand up and expand on the topic. The invitation aspect is coming from the tone and 'I hope', not from 'will'.

Written on an online forum it could mean either a hope or an invitation - I can't tell because writing lacks the tone of speech. But it seems likely to me that it is an invitation for other teaches to add further information.

Comment: I asked a question in a Forum one of teachers answered my question and in the end of his answer, he wrote that sentence.

Comment: Surely in the questioning intonation variant, the invitation aspect is coming from the tone and 'I hope', not from 'will'. 'Will' as request or invitation would be 'Will you ('you' being the colleagues) be so good as to expand on this?' I also thought that Australian Question Intonation was used to describe high rising terminal intonation when it is used in *non-question* situations.

Comment: I appreciate your help, AndyT and Spagirl.

Comment: Please don't block me that I can ask my questions, because in my page it is written that you are maybe being blocked.

Comment: @AndyT I did see that, yes. I just wasn't sure that the subsequent bit didn't take away from the clarity since it is no longer about the role of 'will' was all I meant.

Comment: I can't come there. it is said that I should have 20 reputation.

Comment: @tara I'm not sure what it is you can't do, but you should have enough reputation now, you are on 24.

Comment: Than you so much AndyT and Spagirl.

Comment: @AndyT I don't know how use chat?